# Changing styles dynamically in asp.net mvc application

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, less

We have a multi tenant website. The customer wants to have custom styles according to their standards.

I have a requirement where in the admin settings page there will be option given to the administrator to change the color of nav bar , body text color , anchor color and so on. What would be the best approach to dynamically change the color?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to vary CSS bundles at runtime. Check out this post: http://debeterevormgever.nl/code/dynamic-bundles

Comment: Dynamic bundling idea looks good. Our idea is to change color of individual component.And we are not giving standard colors. We are giving color picker option to select colour for individual component. So once the user selects the custom color, the css file has to be updated and rendered on load. I am looking for a way to update css files dyamically.

Answer (score 0):

According to my Experience you have to create a `Table` for `StyleSheets/CSS`.

I have work on Same type of Requirement I achieved this by the same `Table` approach you have Create your Table with following columns.

```
StyleID int, 
StyleSheetName varchar(100) // you can pass your stylesheet name like Blue,Red,Green etc.
StyleSheetPath varchar(200) // Path for your CSS
IsActive bit // it is use for currently activated CSS and you can check this at your front Side and apply the CSS according to your way.
```

and you can give option to Administrator to change/activate the `theme/css` according to their requirement.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks